# Unexpected Behavior of Extend with a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, immutability

I am trying to understand how extend works in Python and it is not quite doing what I would expect.  For instance:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6].extend(a)
>>> b
>>>
```

But I would have expected:

```
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Why is that returning a None instead of extending the list?

Comment: You expected what `b = [4, 5, 6] + a` does.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `extend()` method appends to the existing array and returns `None`. In your case, you are creating an array — `[4, 5, 6]` — on the fly, extending it and then discarding it. The variable `b` ends up with the return value of `None`.

Answer (score 11):

`list` methods operate in-place for the most part, and return `None`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> b.extend(a)
>>> b
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have pointed out many `list` methods, particularly those that mutate the list, return `None` rather than a reference to the list. The *reason* they do this is so that you don't get confused about whether a copy of the list is made. If you could write `a = b.extend([4, 5, 6])` then is `a` a reference to the same list as `b`? Was `b` modified by the statement? By returning `None` instead of the mutated list, such a statement is made useless, you figure out quickly that `a` doesn't have in it what you thought it did, and you learn to just write `b.extend(...)` instead. Thus the lack of clarity is removed.

Answer (score 4):

`extend` extends its operand, but doesn't return a value. If you had done:

```
b = [4, 5, 6]
b.extend(a)
```

Then you would get the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and while the other answers provide correct explanations, the solution/workaround I liked isn't here.  Using the addition operator will concatenate lists together and return the result.  In my case I was bookkeeping `color` as a 3-digit list and `opacity` as a float, but the library needed color as a 4 digit list with opacity as the 4th digit.  I didn't want to name a throwaway variable, so this syntax suited my needs:

```
color = [1, 1, 0]
opacity = 0.75
plot.setColor(color + [opacity])
```

This creates a new list for opacity on the fly and a new list after the concatenation, but that's fine for my purposes.  I just wanted compact syntax for extending a list with a float and returning the resulting list without affecting the original list or float.