# Add first word to the last of a sentence in python

Tags: python

I have this sentence: 'Johnny Johnny yes papa'. And I want to put the first element of this sentence (as a list) again at the end. This is my code:

```
sentence = 'Johnny Johnny yes papa'
if len(sentence)>0:
  sentence = sentence.split()
  sentence = sentence.extend(sentence[0])
```

But it returns me a none object. I tried this:

```
if len(sentence)>0:
  sentence = sentence.split()
  #sentence = sentence.extend(sentence[0])
  sentence = sentence.append(sentence[0])
```

And again, it returns none. Please, could you help me with this error? The intended list is: `['Johnny','Johnny','yes','papa','Johnny']`

Comment: `list` methods mutate the list in-place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507299/2745495

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending list returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998421/extending-list-returns-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sentence.append(...)` doesn't return anything. It applies on place. You just need to replace `sentence = sentence.append(sentence[0])` with `sentence.append(sentence[0])` line.